# batch command to elist files in folder and add text

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the following in a .bat file:

```
dir *.txt /b/s > FulleFiles.txt
```

That lists all the files in a text file:

```
C:\sample\filea.txt
C:\sample\fileb.txt
C:\sample\filec.txt
```

I now want to add a string after each listing:

```
C:\sample\filea.txt
**corrected**
C:\sample\fileb.txt
**corrected**
C:\sample\filec.txt
**corrected**
```

Is this possible in batch?

Thanks.

Comment: its in a batch script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Example.bat

```
@for /F %%a in ('dir *.txt /b/s') do @(
    echo %%a
    echo **corrected**
)
```

---

see `for /?` for detailed explanation of the for-options.

Comment: I presume you meant to have `>FulleFiles.txt` at the end of that.

Comment: Rejected the edit.   The OP can fill in the details such as file redirection; my answer is meant to show the *key* components only.